# Is it possible to invoke Windows Phone code (i.e. Launch WebBrowserTask) from inside a WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, xaml, webbrowser-control

I have some static webpages as part of my Windows Phone 7 app. It would be very useful however for links that refer to non-local sites on the web to be able to launch the web browser i.e. invoke the `WebBrowserTask`. Also given that the WebBrowser control is embedded in a XAML page it would be great if I could (through javascript for example) invoke behaviours on the page from within the WebBrowser control.

Is this possible?

Comment: For the non-local tasks I found that intercepting the 'Navigating' event on the WebBrowser control and inspecting if e.Uri was an absolute Uri did the trick, however it would still be good to trigger events in the host page ...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need to launch JavaScript in WP7 Browser. There are some security restictions. But most simple stuff works great. Have a look to "**InvokeScript**", **IsScriptEnable** on WebbrowserControl and "**eval**"

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Wb.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(Wb_Navigated);
        MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown);

        Wb.NavigateToString("<html><body><form action='http://google.com/'></form></body></html>");
    }

    void Wb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Wb.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();"); // Throws 80020101
    }

    private void MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Wb.InvokeScript("eval", "document.forms[0].submit();"); // Works
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good from C# to the browser JS, is it possible to do this the other way around?